# How to open new browser window with tab (Not in same window tab)

Tags: visualforce, javascript, browser

I am trying to open new browser window to open with tab.
currently it's display like this,

[image]

I want to display like this,

[image]

VF code:

```
<apex:page >
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(){
        var link = "www.google.com";
        window.open(link,'newwindow','resizable=yes');  
    }
</script>
<apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton onclick="redirect()" value="Click"/>  
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: shared. can you please check

Answer (score 0):

You should use `_blank` instead of `'newwindow'`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(){
        var link = "www.google.com";
        window.open(link,'_blank','resizable=yes');  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: its not working i tried it